# which command should I use when I judge string?

Tags: automationanywhere

I use Automation anywhere today.

I want to know which command should I use. 
(I do not know where is manual about command.)

I want to divide the following work with the characters displayed when a certain button is pressed.

For example, 
if I press the button A, either yes or no will be displayed on the screen. 
If yes displayed, it ok.
but If no, I want to press a different button.
but I don't know which command to judge display.

If you know that, please help me.

Comment: Automation anywhere doesn't provide a terminal like UI. What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Automation anywhere can be used to automate a UI.
If you have a UI which has a button and on pressing that button your UI displays A or B, then you can automate the flow with automation anywhere.

First, you need to use object cloning to clone the button and click on it.

[image: Object cloning to left click]

Second, use object cloning again to get value/name property of result and store it into a variable.

[image: object cloning to get property]

Finally, you can put an if-else/if-elseif condition on the variable and enclose your code in the condition accordingly.

[image: If condition command]

[image: If-else condition]

[image: If-else if condition]

You can also find some examples on [automation anywhere official documentation website](https://docs.automationanywhere.com/search?bundle=&facetreset=yes&q=example)